# Two font issues

Tags: bug

From [this question and answer:](https://korean.stackexchange.com/q/5876/2434)

1. On desktop, the "strong articulation" diacritic, [ ͈] (U+0348), is rendered at bottom-right of the combined character, rather then directly beneath it, like this:

[image: 맛살]

Does this mean we should change desktop font, for example, to DejaVu Sans (which is a standard font for IPA)?

2. On mobile, every 옛한글 syllables are rendered broken jamo-wise. Does this mean we should change mobile font, too?

I don't know a font which solves both these issues.

## Edit

This issue seems to be solved since Stack Exchange dismissed to set a default font. Does this apply to everyone?

Comment: May be it's better to ask this at the stackexchange meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/) since this is probably not specific to just Korean. It will also get more views there.

Comment: @user17915 These particular issues are subjective only to this site. If another site had this issue, it would be Linguistics SE.